# Not able to access .net application running on AWS ECS using docker windows containers

Tags: .net, windows, docker, amazon-ecs

I am hosting .net application in docker windows container and deploying it in AWS ECS (EC2 launch type). .net application is not accessible to the outside world.

When I connect to the .net application using container's IP within the host EC2 machine. I can browse my application.
But when I use my EC2 machine's IP, I can not connect to my application.
I logged into the EC2 and from there I am trying to connect to the application using EC2's public IP, but not able to connect.
I can telnet the port on which task is running in a docker container, added the port in the security group of EC2 machine as well on which application is bind to a docker container to host

Comment: can you show you task definition port mapping?

Comment: I think the port in not bind with the host which you are expecting.

Comment: i am using terraform to create task definition. here is my code for port mapping:
"portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": ${container_port},
        "hostPort": 0
      }
    ],

Comment: Port 0 will be used for dynamic port mapping. At run time it will get the port number which is available on the host machine. Every time when I run it is giving me the new port.
One thing I noticed is that I am deploying 3 services, out of which one is deployed successfully which is frontend application.
But othe rtwo backend applications are not deploying and the difference I got is backend application is using "Swagger" as API tool.

Comment: does your security group allow all traffic?

Comment: Yes, it does.
I noticed that when I checked logs for IIS server, it is giving me 301 status code when I deploy on a port other than 80

Comment: Finally, I am able to resolve the issue.
The issue is with swagger's redirection. When i am deploying swagger using docker container, somehow swagger needs same port from host in which it is running in container.

Comment: good awsome keep it up